# App Icon not showing up after Xcode shows the disconnected message

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, icons

My app icon do not show up on my device after I see the disconnected message from Xcode. I do see the app icon before that error.

How my problem occurs: Once I see the disconnected message, I unplug my cable, plug it again and build. Then, I see my app icon disappear. I tried to run my simulator. I do see the app icon. After that, I removed the whole AppIcon set in Assets.xcassets and add a new AppIcon set. Same thing still happens: AppIcon does show in my simulator but does not show in my device. **I am wondering whether the disconnected issue crashes something in my device?**

I always face a issue that my device vibrates constantly. To solve this issue, I unplug it and plug it again.

Comment: Check your cable, there might be a cable problem, Are you using original cable. Disconnection occurs when the cable is too old or duplicate.

Comment: Ya. It is original cable.But, I do see the app icon before the error

Comment: Check that you are not running the app using distribution or Adhoc provisioning  profile. It should be development one

Comment: Yes. They are all in development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by

1. delete the whole assets file and create a new one
2. put back all the images
3. resize my icon again